# Did the Waif possibly turn into Jaqen after attacking Arya?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

After hitting Arya in *Game of Thrones* S06E02, I assumed the Waif left and Jaqen came along just after, but it occurred to me that they might have been the same person. Is this possible? Is it likely?

Comment: I don't see where this is important. There are great chances that both the woman and the man Arya saw during this episode are the same person, or no one, if you prefer. They could be 2 different person or 1, I don't think it matters story-wise since we know that who ever surrounded Arya so far were no ones. No one can become anyone, so a male becoming a female wouldn't be too far fetched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As seen in the Season 5 finale, Jaqen turned into a frail man who turned into Arya. The Waif turned into Jaqen. All by removing their faces, as no one before the Many Faced God.

It's completely possible that no one did it again in Season 6 Episode 2. Considering that the idea is that no one can become anyone when allowed, it's a given that it's possible. **They have done it before, after all.**

But both Jaqen and the Waif have been seen together at the same time. There is at least two people with no names, so unless there was a need for Jaqen and the Waif to be the same person, the simpler explanation is that they were not. After all, a girl enjoyed picking on the beggar, but a man took pity on her. In the novels, the two people are specifically separate characters.

---

**Side note:** The TV show deviated from the novels. [The man that Arya meets in Braavos is *"The Kindly Man"*, and is not Jaqen, in face or name.](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jaqen_H%27ghar) The only connection being that they are both Faceless Men. In the show, it's **left intentionally vague if the Jaqen in Westeros from Season 2 is the same person as a man in Braavos in Season 5.**. As the Faceless Men view themselves as no one, as servants of the Many-Faced God, this is more in line with their belief system.

Comment: I know, I just don't understand the point of asking for precisions when the anwser makes it even more ambiguous. At this point it's a question of opinion.

Comment: @Alexandre 'Maybe' is also an answer.

Comment: @Alexandre Cast your votes or use your flags; railing against the question and answer isn't going to accomplish anything.

Comment: I like this answer, I hadn't realized that they had both been shown at once but also changed from one to the other. I'd assume the answer here is possibly they were the same person but not necessarily. It clarifies whether or not it was possible at least.

Comment: As an avid book reader and show watcher, I confer that this answer is perfect!

Comment: @Alexandre If you are answering to my comment, please use @. You cannot expect me to check every question I made a comment to. And to answer your comment: No. There is a difference between your example and a good answer based on a thorough analysis. The subject   of this SE is specific and sometimes simply **there is none definitive answer**. This doesn't mean that we are not supposed to answer at all.

Comment: So basically, it's impossible to tell if anyone did it because we know for a fact that no one does it all the time, and therefore anyone can be no one at any given moment..

Answer (score 0):

I too got the feeling that both are the same person. Their personal traits like the way they stand and walk looks the same, however that is because both are no one. This may be a part of the training also.

However we cannot conclude anything at this point. To me, it seems that this is the point or reason behind that particular scene; to show that "no one"s are really no one.

However, we are sure there are many people serving as 'no one'. And the Waif is not same person whom Arya met in Westeros. However, the person shown in this particular episode can be the same person. And the show intends to depict that they are the same.

Comment: They had different clothes, though. She had an almost-black tunic with white details, he had billowy off-white robes. I'm not aware of them ever magically transforming clothes? The important thing, however, is that *Arya* doesn't at any time know who is who.