# Why is Jaqen H'ghar helping Arya Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As in the 2nd season of *Game of Thrones* where Jaqen helped Arya to kill the torturer The Tickler, why is he helping her again in season 6?

Comment: A man with Jaqen H'ghar's face is not necessarily Jaqen H'ghar...

Comment: A man might be helped by a girl, and repay that favor, but that does not make a man no longer interested in a girl's future. And aside from that, is a man really helping a girl? Or is he helping the faceless god? Or both?

Comment: To extend the comment: In the books Jaqen is not mentioned in Braavos, nor is it implied, that he could be the "Kindly Man". During an interview, Tom Wlaschiha (who plays Jaqen) said, the show runners just wanted him back, so they (also) gave him the part of the "Kindly Man".

Comment: Why does any group train new members?

Comment: I'd think bigger. How did a man who can literally change his face at will manage to get captured at all? I think bigger forces are at play and he set himself in that position to meet Arya. Then linking back to your question he's helping her because it is his gods will.

Comment: The Faceless men are basically Assasins. They're also a bit religious but still are Assasins. And Arya is not being helped, she is being trained so that she can help then, in what? Assasinations.

Comment: To extend the comment even more, in the books, Jaqen in Westeros and The Kindly Man are supposed to be two distinct characters. Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52491/did-the-waif-possibly-turn-into-jaqen-after-attacking-arya

Answer (score 2):

Jaqen H'ghar has seen exceptional talent in Arya Stark. This is why he decided to help and later train her. He even states that "A girl had many talents" (Season 6, Episode 7). You could say that she was a personal favourite.

The Faceless Men do generally not accept children to be trained, so it can already be seen as great honour that she was accepted. Assuming that the Faceless Men are not only pure hitmen but have a purpose in serving the Many-faced God (which imho at least in the series is open to debate) it could also have religious reasons as trained Arya could be a powerful instrument in the religious struggles to come.

Comment: Nope. I clearly remember Faceless man mentioning that he will kill 3 persons of her wish because she saved his life.

Comment: @BoringMovies: Those three lives were essentially a gift for the kindness she showed the three prisoners. A butcher would give you meat, a baker would give you bread, an assassin gives you free assasinations. But the existence of that gift doesn't preclude (a) Jaqen seeing potential in Arya nor (b) Jaqen additionally giving her the coin as well. Him training her isn't a selfless gift either, he is recruiting her into his order for the order's benefit (at least, that's the idea before she leaves).

Answer (score -1):

1. There's no Jaqen H'ghar :-)
2. The man is not helping her. The girl came to learn from him. He trains her and wants her to serve.